# CSS Grid layout max-content does not work as expected in Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I used CSS Grid layout to create a basic layout for a page, and I worked originally in Chrome while doing that. I tested this now also in Firefox and noticed some behaviour that I don't understand and that doesn't seem to follow the specification as I understand it.

I created a simplified example that shows the behaviour. The problem is the height of the search-header div. This is set to max-content and should be just as large as needed to fit the contained element.

This works as expected in Chrome 66, but not in Firefox 52 ESR or Firefox 62 Developer Edition (all on Linux). In Firefox the search-header div is larger and extends beyond the contained span. This does only happen if there are the input elements in the search-sidebar div, and the more of them I add the larger the search-header div gets.

Am I misunderstanding how max-content is supposed to work? Why are Firefox and Chrome behaving differently in this case? And how can I fix this?

```css
.search {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-sidebar {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: #CCFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: #FFCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-table {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background: #FFFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-sidebar">
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-header">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="search-table"></div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in Firefox:

[image]

And this is how it looks in Chrome, and how it is intended to look:

[image]

Comment: At first glance, looks like a Firefox bug. But replacing `auto` with `1fr` for the 2nd row size appears to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would start with a review of browser support for the `max-content` sizing value.

Here are a few observations:

- The `min-content`, `max-content` and `fit-content()` values are all new. They were introduced in [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#sizing-values). So full browser support is already suspect.
- A review of browser support tables at [**caniuse.com**](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content) reveals that `max-content` has full support in Chrome, but only limited support in Firefox. It also requires the `-moz-` prefix to work in FF.
- A review of `max-content` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility) also shows that `max-content` works fine in Chrome, but has limited support and requires the `-moz-` prefix in Firefox. MDN also says that `max-content` is [experimental and should not be used in production code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Syntax).

Those items may describe the reason for the Chrome / Firefox discrepancy in your layout.

But putting all that aside, you don't even need `max-content` to make your layout work. You can use `max-content`, `min-content` or `auto` on the first row.

Then make the second row `1fr`, which forces the second row to consume all remaining height in the container, squeezing all free space out of the first row.

The `auto` value does not do this because it functions under a different algorithm than `fr`.

- [`fr` sizing algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-find-fr-size)
- [`auto` sizing algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-stretch)

So, for the reasons described above, make this simple adjustment to your code:

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
```

```css
.search {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-sidebar {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: #CCFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: #FFCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-table {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background: #FFFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-sidebar">
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
        <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
        <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
        <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-header">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="search-table"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lajdxog6/10/)

Answer (score 4):

As [Ilya Streltsyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533215/ilya-streltsyn) comments, replacing `auto` for `1fr` solves the issue. Any browser that supports `display: grid` will support `fr`, and there's virtually no difference between `auto` and one single use of `fr`: both refer to the entirety of the unclaimed space.

```
grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
```

```css
.search {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-sidebar {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: #CCFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: #FFCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-table {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background: #FFFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-sidebar">
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Label:</label>
      <div><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-header">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="search-table"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the immediate issue, but I still don't understand if this is simply a Firefox bug, or if I'm misunderstanding something in the spec.

Comment: Even if 2022 this was a problem for me. In my case I had to replace 100% with 1fr to get it to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Mad Scientist, I do not think there is anything wrong with your code.
The structure is perfect, both css and html.

I have tested your code out on my localhost on Edge, Chrome and Mozilla and they are working properly. the only issue is with IE 11 and Opera, they do not support display grid.