# CSS Grid area size based on content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am restructuring a project to use the grid layout. The site layout is as shown below:

Current structure with content marked with pattern

[image: Current structure with content marked with pattern]

The main content is dynamic, so when loading the area with new content, the previous areas expand in height adding a lot of empty space as shown here:

Problematic content changes

[image: Problematic content changes]

I have tried a whole bunch of different values for `grid-template-rows` and still end up with the same problem.

What should I be doing to expand ***only*** the bottom area of the central column even when it has no content and keep the remaining areas the same size of the content inside them?

The reason for not splitting this up into different grids / flex layouts is that I plan to move the left column into the central column for mobile devices.

This is the code for the main grid container:

```
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 255px calc(100% - 255px - 330px) 330px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, auto) 100%;
    align-items: start;
    grid-template-areas:
        "sidebar flash ads"
        "sidebar profile ads"
        "sidebar form ads"
        "sidebar filterArea ads"
        "sidebar categories ads"
        "sidebar hiddenArea ads"
        "sidebar sticky ads"
        "sidebar messages ads";
    min-height: 0;
```

Some of those vaules may look weird, but I've had to put specific widths for the columns as sometimes the content would overshoot the width of the central column if the width is kept as `auto`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Weird part is no matter what I did earlier (this included), I ended up with the same result. I'm gonna chalk that up to my docker-sync being it's difficult self. Thanks so much!

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51358176/3597276